# CorePlot - unable to zoom using 2 plot spaces

Tags: zooming, core-plot, scatter-plot

I have 2 scatter plots in a single plot. Both the plots have the same x-axis but the y scale is different. So I have created a new plot space.

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

CPTXYPlotSpace *newPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.newPlotSpace;
newPlotSpace.identifier = @"Fund PlotSpace";
[graph addPlotSpace:newPlotSpace];

// 2 - Create the two plots
CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
aaplPlot.delegate = self;
[graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

CPTScatterPlot *fdPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
fundingPlot.delegate = self;
[graph addPlot:fdPlot toPlotSpace:newPlotSpace];
```

I also have enabled user interaction

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

CPTXYPlotSpace *newPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.newPlotSpace;
newPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
```

I have also done this

```
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 

self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];
```

But the second plot does not zoom. I am unable to understand why.

**Edit**

Here is my full code

[image]

Comment: The second plot space is working correctly except for user interaction, correct? What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: @EricSkroch Yes. Exactly! I started with the sample code given here - http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/downloads/CorePlotDemo2.zip. I dont think it is the latest version. Should I use CorePlot 1.4 to solve the problem?

Comment: @EricSkroch - I see version 1.5.1 here - https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot. But am not clear as to which folders to download and copy to my project.I am unable to locate **CorePlotHeaders**

Comment: Download the [zip file](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases/download/release_1.5.1/CorePlot_1.5.1.zip). Unzip it. The iOS and Mac libraries and headers are in the "Binaries" folder.

Comment: @EricSkroch I used CorePlot 1.5.1 but still have the same problem.

Comment: @EricSkroch Is there any particular order in which the above steps should be done?

Comment: The setup order shouldn't matter. Does either plot space have a delegate that might be affecting the zooming behavior?

Comment: @EricSkroch I have not implemented any delegate function for either of the plot spaces but the first plot space zooms and the second does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating two new plot spaces but only adding one to the graph. The one with user interaction enabled in `-configureGraph` is different from the one created in `-configurePlots` and added to the graph.

The `-newPlotSpace` method creates a new plot space object for you. In `-configureGraph`, give it an identifier and add it to the graph (move those lines from `-configurePlots`). When you need to refer to it later (e.g., in `-configurePlots`), do this:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *newPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)[graph plotSpaceWithIdentifier:@"Fd Plot Space"];
```